# Sumar los digitos de cada elemento en una lista

Tags: python

necesito ayuda con un programa para sumar los digitos de cada elemento en una lista, esto es lo que he intentado: lo ue espero imprima sea
33
35
39
46......

```
lista=['383847','6374672','387749','3994885','934983','3994875']
for num in lista:
    num[0]+num[1]+num[2]+num[3]+num[4]+num[5]
print(num)
```

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de 

como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado. 

No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que necesitas en vez de hardcodear el indexado como haces, es un ciclo `for in` anidado que itere sobre cada carácter (dígito). Además necesitas una variable que actúe de acumulador para la suma. Si tus números ya son cadenas no necesitas la conversión a `str`, si no lo son debes hacerla para extraer los dígitos, aunque hay otras aproximaciones.

```
lista = [2334, 5678, 6543, 78]
for número in lista:
    suma = 0
    for dígito in str(número):
        suma += int(dígito)
    print(suma)
```

O más eficiente, usando el builtin `sum` y una expresión generadora:

```
lista = [2334, 5678, 6543, 78]

for número in lista:
    print(sum((int(dígito) for dígito in str(número))))
```

---

```
lista = [2334, 5678, 6543, 78]
print(*(sum(int(digito) for digito in str(número)) for número in lista))
```

o una aproximación funcional con `map`:

```
lista = [2334, 5678, 6543, 78]

for número in lista:
    print(sum(map(int, str(número))))
```

---

```
lista = [2334, 5678, 6543, 78]

print(*map(lambda número: sum(map(int, str(número))), lista))
```

Comment: todo un salvavidas gracias! !!

Comment: Hola FJSevilla la única observación que te haría es respecto a los acentos amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Estas realizando un bucle que itera sobre la lista, esos valores los puedes convertir a entero para poder sumarlos mediante la función [**int()**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int).

Crea una variable para almacenar el `total`, donde agregas la suma de los números enteros.

```
lista=['383847','6374672','387749','3994885','934983','3994875']
total=0
for num in lista:
    total += int(num)
print(total)
```

como salida obtendrías:

```
16071011
```

---

Actualización:

Si deseas obtener la suma de los digitos que contiene cada elemento en el array

```
lista=['383847','6374672','387749','3994885','934983','3994875']

for elemento in lista:
    numeros = map(int, str(elemento))
    print(sum(numeros))
```

Tendrías como salida:

```
33
35
38
46
36
45
```

Comment: sí es algo así solo que necesito me sume los digitos de cada elemento, que en el primero por ejemplo me imprima 33

Comment: Ok @kevindevroon he actualizado mi respuesta, solo recuerda realizar tus preguntas de forma detallada, agregando la información suficiente que permita a la comunidad ayudarte, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

hay **muchos** errores en tu codigo, los describire parte por parte.

Los elementos de la lista son de tipo `str`, no `int` ni `float`, estos dos utlimos tipos son numeros, y el primero es texto, sumar strings entre si es equivalente a lo siguiente: `string = "a" + "b"` donde `string` es igual a `"ab"`, para solucionar el error de el tipo de dato debes de volver a declarar la lista, pero ahora sin las comillas.

```
lista =  [383847,6374672,387749,3994885,934983,3994875]
```

y ya dentro de el ciclo `for` no es necesario que hagas `num[0]+num[1]+num[2]+num[3]+num[4]+num[5]`, para empezar es incorrecto, pues estas tomando el index de la variable `num` y no de la lista, en la primera iteración del ciclo pasaría esto:

```
num = "383847"
num[0] = "3"
num[1] = "8"
num[3] = "3"
etc..
```

En segunda, escribir cada index manualmente es ineficiente, que pasaria si no conoces la logitud de la lista? para eso esta el ciclo for, hace las iteraciones una por una, lo mejor seria tener declarada una variable donde se guarde el total de la suma e ir agregando los valores en cada iteracion.

```
total = 0
for num in lista:
    total += num
```

por ultimo, el `print` al final tambien esta incorrecto, al poner `print(num)` estarias pidiendole a la computadora que te muestre el ultimo valor en el que se itero en el ciclo for, en este caso `"3994875"`

```
lista =  [383847,6374672,387749,3994885,934983,3994875]
total = 0
for num in lista:
     total += num
print(total)
```